# Searching has a huge flaw

Tags: support, bug, feature-request, search

Why is each kana mora or each kanji character considered a separate word when searching?  Here is an image of the rsults of me searching for `よろしく` on meta.  You can see that the first three results have the whole phrase, but after that, it picks up **any** question/answer that has **any** of the characters in it.  If you look under the "Advanced Search Tips", it says you can use double-quotes to search for an exact word or phrase.  This works fine for English text, but again fails for Japanese text.

This makes searching in Japanese worthless, especially on the main site.  Is there something that can be done about this?

[image: searching meta]

Comment: I agree. At the moment, I think it's still best to use Google search: [site:japanese.stackexchange.com "よろしく"](https://www.google.com/search?hl=ja&q=site%3Ajapanese.stackexchange.com%20%22%E3%82%88%E3%82%8D%E3%81%97%E3%81%8F%22)

Comment: We don't have an estimate on how much effort it'd take to change/fix this at the moment. We are currently working on better supporting non-English alphabets, though, so we'll likely revisit this while we're at it.

Answer (score 3):

This can be fixed by making the searching algorithm refuse to split any CJK characters unless a space is present; even enclosing the characters in quotes, the searching expects a space after the quoted characters (due to it being focused on Latin sentence structure), and so gives incorrect results.

You could probably [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) this and a dev on Stack Exchange will see it.

Small oversight due to language barriers, I think.

Comment: Do you mean to simply add the [meta-tag:feature-request] to this question, or open a new topic somewhere else?

Comment: @istrasci I'll ping a dev about it, but I'd add it to the question

Comment: Actually fixing search would require some language awareness, I think.  You can't insist on spaces, nor can you always match individual characters.  (Maybe when the Japanese Stack Overflow is launched they'll license some Japanese-aware search technology.)